# Swipe.js strange result with Media Queries

Tags: javascript, html, css, swipe

Im having an issue while using media queries with "Swipe".

If i open my website in "tablet" mode, the swipe works in Mobile and Tablet forms, Desktop wont.

BUT, if i save my files again in the text editor and open them in Desktop mode, they work, but not in Mobile and Tablet.

```css
.swipe {
 overflow: hidden;
 visibility: hidden;
 position: relative;
 -ms-touch-action: none;/*pan-y on desktop*/
 touch-action: none; /*pan-y on desktop*/
}

.swipe-wrap{
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;
}

.swipe-wrap > div {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="slidepassos" class="swipe slidepassos">
 <div class="swipe-wrap">
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="passo-um">
   <div class="passoscont">
   <h1>How?</h1>
   <h2>Step 1:</h2>
   <img src="img/passoumilu.svg" class="passoumilu">
   <p>Do your coach oriented WOD. Remember, know your limits and try to break them.</p>
   <img src="img/swipeleft.png" class="swipeleftcontent">
   <img src="img/swipeleftdesktop.png" class="swipeleftcontent-desktop">
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="passo-dois">
   <div class="passoscont">
   <h1>How?</h1>
   <h2>Step 2:</h2>
   <img src="img/passodoisilu.svg" class="passoumilu">
   <p>Now your coach gets the results of your efforts and publish them in the box page on Crossagenda.</p>
    <img src="img/swipeleft.png" class="swipeleftcontent">
    <img src="img/swipeleftdesktop.png" class="swipeleftcontent-desktop">
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="passo-tres">
   <div class="passoscont">
   <h1>How?</h1>
   <h2>Step 3:</h2>
   <img src="img/passotresilu.svg" class="passoumilu">
   <p>Remember, get up your energy levels and while you're at it, check your WOD results and progress in Crossagenda.</p>
    <img src="img/swipeleft.png" class="swipeleftcontent">
    <img src="img/swipeleftdesktop.png" class="swipeleftcontent-desktop">
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mySlides">
   <div class="passo-quatro">
   <div class="passoscont">
   <h1>How?</h1>
   <h2>Step 4:</h2>
   <img src="img/passoquatroilu.svg" class="passoumilu">
   <p>Chat with your colleagues in our app or poke them in your next class ;)</p>
    <img src="img/swipeleft.png" class="swipeleftcontent">
    <img src="img/swipeleftdesktop.png" class="swipeleftcontent-desktop">
   </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 window.mySwipe = Swipe(document.getElementById('slidepassos'));
 </script>
```

Comment: are you using this swipe.js? https://github.com/thebird/Swipe
May I suggest you using hammer.js (http://hammerjs.github.io/)
IMO, it's more bullet proof than a 4 year old js lib.. (oh and no I'm not affiliated to hammer.js)

Comment: Can we see the js for this project?

Comment: @funkysoulzh yes, im using that one.